# Get the ID of a user in REST API 2013 Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, rest, designer-workflow

I am using:

```
_api/web/siteusers?$select=Id,Title&$filter=startswith(Title, 'FirstName LastName')
```

But my issue is that `Title` is not a unique value.  We can have more than one user with the same name.  I want to filter on a unique value like `loginName` or `email`.

Comment: are you looking for a SharePoint Designer option or a URL?

Comment: Try something like `_api/web/siteusers?$select=Id,Title&$filter=Email eq 'emailAddress'` or `_api/web/siteusers?$select=Id,Title&$filter=LoginName eq 'userlogin'`

Comment: @Cynthia, did you found the answer? Is so, please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a script this might help a little:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
        var loginName = "";
        var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

            function GetCurrentUser() {

            var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
            var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

                $.ajax({
                  url : requestUri,
                  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
                  headers : requestHeaders,
                  success : onSuccessA,
                  error : onErrorA
                });
            }

            function onSuccessA(data, request){

                // alert("Success One");
                // cutting of i:0#.w|
                var loginName = data.d.LoginName.split('|')[1];

                var repOne = "%5C";  
                var repTwo = "%2E";
                // alert("before replace: " + loginName);

                loginName = loginName.replace(/\\/g, repOne); // replace \ with %5C
                loginName = loginName.replace(/\./g, repTwo); // replace . with %2E

                alert("after replace: " + loginName);

            }

            function onErrorA(error) {

              alert(error);
            }

            GetCurrentUser();

        });

    </script>
```

But if you using SharePoint Desinger you can use the lookup option and there select Workflow: Context and Initiator

[image]

Hope I helped a little.